# How do I make the Sencha ExtJS Application assembly with the specified locale option of Cmd?

Tags: extjs

The command `sencha app build --locale en production` does not work. Here is the error text:

```
C:\@repositories\element2\client\ews-office-app>sencha app build --locale en production
Sencha Cmd v6.2.2.36
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 6.2.0.981 from C:\@repositories\element2\client\ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[ERR] No build descriptors selected
```

Comment: Have you tried `sencha app build production --locale en`?

Comment: @Alexander Tried it. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build descriptor from your app.json. 
If you have a build config like this

```
"builds": {
    "classic": {
        "toolkit": "classic",
        "locales": [
            "de",
            "es"
            "en",
        ]
    }
},
```

you can specifiy the build by using a combination of toolkit, theme and locale:

```
sencha app build classic-en production
```

if you use a specific theme, e.g. *theme-foo-bar*, you need to add it too:

```
sencha app build classic-theme-foo-bar-en production
```